# Getting the current logged in user name when using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Its a coupon system app using Spring security, spring MVC,
now.
when the app starts, I need to somehow initialize the current logged in user into the controller.

Issue is:

1. If I try to get the current user via SecurityContextHolder it is impossible because it seems like spring is initializing the controllers before the security so I cannot get it in the controller.

Is there anything I'm missing? a different approach of getting the current logged in user after he logs in?

Comment: What about request.getUserPrincipal().getName() from a controller method that is called after login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called `@AuthenticationPrincipal`.
You can inject it in  controller method like this:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public void get(@AuthinticationPrincipal User user){ ... }
```

Here is [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal)

Alternatively, you can create your own annotation and custom argument resolver, and inject whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly! exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution 1: Principal principal*

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", ""})
    public String start(Principal principal, Model model) {
           String currentUser = principal.getName();       
           return currentUser;
    }
```

---

*Solution 2: Authentication authentication*

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", ""})
public String currentUserName(Authentication authentication) {
        return authentication.getName();
}
```

---

*Solution 3: SecurityContextHolder*

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
  String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
  String username = principal.toString();
}
```

[More Here](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security)